# How to force email client to open when submitting form

Tags: html, form-submit

I have a HTML form with a submit button that emails the input from the form fields to a specific email when clicked.  But right now, when the submit button is clicked, it just pops up a little window saying the website is trying to send email from my Outlook and asking if I will allow it.  How can I make it so that Outlook opens up and I can review the email, with all the input, before it's sent?  I'm just using the most straightforward method of submitting this form, `form action=mailto...`, `method=POST`, and an `<input type="submit" />` button.

Comment: Do you have any scripting language such as PHP, ASP, JavaScript running? This is a "security" issue and is designed to stop websites spamming from users computers

Comment: So, you want to be able to bypass the warning, which is there for the user's security? I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do it. It's probably better to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There is no way to override the conformation dialog, and the system depends on the user having a compatible email client installed and configured (which makes the approach [hideously unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)).

If you want to deal with forms, submit them over http(s), not email.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a browser to run an external program, that would be a huge security hole. Mail clients are one of the allowed external programs, but that still required a users input.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is to use an HTML form and a server based form processor.  This requires a little bit of coding knowledge.  Based on your question, it doesn't sound like you have a lot of experience with server-side coding-- May I suggest one of the many server side plugins that will process the form and email you the results? http://www.tectite.com/ has PHP FormMail which is easy to use and configure.

As has been stated above, you can't force a browser to open an email client-- Furthermore many users use gmail, hotmail, yahoo mail and may use the browser as their client.  Your solution would exclude a large segment of users from responding!

Good luck.